# qiskit - Creating your own ExperimentResultData object

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Could someone guide me on how to create my own `qiskit.result.models.ExperimentResultData` object? I would simply like to create an object with some self-created dict of counts.

Creating `qiskit.result.models.ExperimentalResults` object is somehow easy, since by calling it from `qiskit.result.models.ExperimentResults`, I simply pass the required attributes. But somehow I was not able to figure out how to do the same with `qiskit.result.models.ExperimentResultData`, which should be passed as "data" attribute to `qiskit.result.models.ExperimentalResults` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by simply creating an instance of the class. This can be done as follows

```
from qiskit.validation import base
raw_counts = {'0x0': 4, '0x2': 10}
data = models.ExperimentResultData(counts=base.Obj(**raw_counts))
```

There are lot of examples of how to do this in the [testing file](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/0caab4a3ec1f8ced437be59d1e77657922771392/test/python/result/test_result.py) for these classes.

Comment: Ah, great, thank you for the solution and great reference! I was only looking at files in the qiskit package (downloaded via pip) and I did not find such testing file, so I'll use github one for future issues.

Comment: @FilipMaciejewski If this answer helped, consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark at the left.